# Issues with .xib files

Tags: ios, xib

So I've "accidentally" created 3 nib files, I can swipe right and left between three views (.xib files) however, I have some issues regarding the layouts and auto-layouts, for one device it looks great, the others.... not so hot.

I'm trying to add a few images and a button, however, the placement is totally weird.

How can I address this issue?

Also, could I just use a ViewController to present itself over the .xib file if possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can consider on your situation. 
Firstly, You can connect each of these 3 nib files with a view controller. Then you can use a page view controller to manage all these three view controllers. Page view controller supports swipe right and left for showing different view controllers. You only need to make each view controller layout correct then all the swipe actions will be handled by page view controller. 
Secondly, you can create a root view controller with 3 sub view controllers. You should call rootViewController.addChildController method to add these 3 sub view controllers. But you need to be carefully about the layout of these 3 sub view controllers since they are only part of the root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check auto layout constraints for your display issue. Some times auto layout leads problem for your display.

And for three .nib files you can simple use view controller and add it to the root view when you need it and remove it from root view when you want to remove it.